# inApp restore: number of restored transactions zero

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, restore

I have followed the second answer(by Brian Noah) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021932/in-app-purchases-restore-button) 
to implement inapp restore functionality. During testing I just bought an inapp item and reinstalled the app. But now, when I try to restore the purchase the number of received restored transactions shows zero. What I'm doing wrong here? please help me.

After I call 'restoreCompletedTransactions', the method

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

is getting called.

But the method

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

is not getting called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not all items types can be restored.  Consumables for example can't be restored; if you want to restore these, implement your own restore scheme on a server. [Here's](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf) a document from Apple with a little more details.