# Restore Button for in-app

Tags: in-app-purchase

Apple rejected App saying there is no "Restore button".. The App is actually done in Unity..But I don't have the Unity Code now.. I have the Xcode project and I uploaded the app for the 1st time with this Xcode project.. Apple rejected because there is no restore button.

Now I need to add "Restore button" and upload again to store.. Can I add the restore button from the Xcode project.. Many say "Yes" and many say"No".. A help would be appreciated...

Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Add a button to the appropriate storyboard, and in the implementation add a call to :

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]   restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

And of course, provide the content that was restored.   Whatever it was.   See this for more help: 
[In app purchases restore Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021932/in-app-purchases-restore-button)

Of course if you make the update in xcode, you'll be out of sync with Unity, so do it there first and regenerate.   If you've "lost" the unity code, you are stuck figuring out the generated xcode project.

Comment: Thats not helpful.. can't access the UI..  Please help at least to remove the in-app....

Comment: Maybe you should focus on getting your system restored so you can access the UI.   The UI is there to provide the capabilities you need to create and publish projects as well as to help you develop.    I'm not sure how you are making changes and developing without the UI.   Can you just add a call to create the button you need as a sub of something in the appropriate view?