# Restore in-app purchase with Swift 3

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, swift3

I am trying to work with in app purchases in Swift 3. I can successfully make payments on my test device. I have a restore button on top of the screen when clicked should restore all the previous purchases. Here is the code that I use to restore. My queue in the function is always empty. Please help me fix this.

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    for transaction in queue.transactions{
        let trans: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodID = trans.payment.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
            case "some_iap":
                print("Do something")
                finishTransaction(trans)

            default: break
            }
    }
    updatePurchases()
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
    print("error in restore")
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for trans in queue.transactions{
        let trans: SKPaymentTransaction = trans as SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.transactionState.rawValue)
        switch (trans.transactionState) {
        case .purchased:
            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
            case "some_iap":
                print("do something")
                updatePurchases()
                finishTransaction(trans)

            default:
                print("defualt")
                finishTransaction(trans)
            }

        case .failed: break

        default: break
        }
    }
}

func finishTransaction(_ trans:SKPaymentTransaction){
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(trans)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Solution for Swift 3

```
//Step 1 Call from button Restore Purchase
func restore() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

//Step 2 Get transactions
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {

        switch transaction.transactionState {
         case .purchased:
                print("Product Purchased")
                unlockApp()
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

                break;
            case .failed:
                print("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            case .restored:
                print("Already Purchased")
                unlockApp()

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}




//If an error occurs, the code will go to this function
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
    //Handle Error
}
```

Comment: It has been expressed that this code might be vulnerable, and could allow anyone to restore purchases for free without having to pay for them in the first place. Is that true?

Comment: yes its true. `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished ` will called everytime you hit the Restore button. so you need to check with identifier and then restore

Comment: @BradLarson Updated answer for correct implementation. It will only restore if user has already purchased. For future reference